# Migrating game data from Windows 8.1 to Android 4.4

Tags: windows, data-transfer

I have been playing Asphalt 8: Airborne on Windows 8.1, and now I want to continue playing it on Android without starting over. I read that you cannot save data on cross-platforms.

Can I go into a folder in Windows and copy current data to Android? Otherwise, are there other options?

Comment: @Beron as far as the edit if this is what you really want to achieve then you need to use the help option in your game wherein you will have a chance to contact the customer support and you may tell him your problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get around it by copying the save data yourself from your PC to your phone. The reason the game doesn't support cross-platform sync isn't just because it doesn't know how to copy the files. (Obviously it does, or you wouldn't be able to sync on the same platform either.) It's because the different versions of the game have different data formats. So even if you did copy the save data, the game on Android wouldn't be able to understand it. It might ignore it completely, or it might crash trying to load it.

It was the developer's choice to do it this way. They obviously didn't think that spending time on making the different versions compatible was worthwhile.

Answer (score -2):

You need to log in, once you do whatever progress you do is saved on the cloud, be it that, if you do log in on another OS , it will continue from where you left it. 
References or more information , please visit : 
http://support.gameloft.com/OnlineAndSocial/showSelection/283/

Comment: Nope. Same link: "Please note that only devices with the same operating system (Android, iOS, Windows 8) can be synchronized."